# System.DllNotFoundException on asp.net

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5

I have an asp.net 3.5 application. When i try to load the application it says: Exception Details: System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'VSPerf100.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

The application works fine on my win 7 machine. i tried the same on win server 2008 r2 where in i get the above message.

Any idea what i am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you verify that the DLL is in the bin folder of the app?  Or maybe its not loaded into the GAC when it should be?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is related to code profiling. You could try turning it off on your build (or installing the profiling DLLs on your server)